# How to set a column as an index in dateframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict like this:

```
   dict = {'open': 245.04, 'high': 245.769, 'low': 244.7, 'close': 245.51, 'volume': 1489478, 'datetime': 1584451800000}
```

I want to convert it into a dateframe data and set datetime as an index.

So I tried:

```
data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict,orient='index')
```

And then I received:

```
                     0
open      2.450400e+02
high      2.457690e+02
low       2.447000e+02
close     2.455100e+02
volume    1.489478e+06
datetime  1.584452e+12
```

How to set datetime as an index?

Comment: What you mean index, can you show us the output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC notice do not name the `dict` with dict , since python have the variable  called `dict`

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index').T.set_index('datetime')
                open     high    low   close     volume
datetime                                               
1.584452e+12  245.04  245.769  244.7  245.51  1489478.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,can you tell me what is T?

Comment: @williamfaith https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html